# Ask Ubuntu's contact page seems to be broken

Tags: discussion

The first week of January 2021, I submitted two questions to https://askubuntu.com/contact. In week two, I submitted another. I have yet to get a response to any of these questions. Not even the usual automated response that virtually all websites send these days.

I suspect this is broken. Can someone look into this, please?

Comment: After three weeks, there is no indication that anyone is even looking into this issue.     Perhaps this is the wrong place to post this? If so, where would be a better place to post this?

Comment: It is now five weeks after I asked this question and there is NO response. Is there anyone who actually READS this forum? Is there a different place I should ask this question? Perhaps "Ask Ubuntu Meta Meta" exists?

Comment: Please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296310

Comment: That is shockingly similar to my experience! And that was 4 years ago! Obviously, they haven't yet fixed that issue!

Comment: Richard, which issue are you talking about?

Answer (score 4):

<s>Firstly, no "automated response" is sent by Stack Exchange when you submit tickets in the contact page. [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/961355) was said by [Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/146126/grace-note) (a Stack Exchange employee):</s>

> <s>When you reach out through Contact Us, [you receive the following confirmation message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJoho.png). Sending a followup email that just echoes that seems redundant and not particularly any more convincing.</s>

Actually, automated responses are generally sent. But there were some issues because of which they weren't sent. Read this for more information: [Since when did Stack Exchange start sending automated mails when one contacts Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368740)

---

> I suspect this is broken. Can someone look into this please?

Did you see something like this after pressing submit:

[image]

If you did see something like this, it is not broken :)

---

> After three weeks, there is no indication that anyone is even looking into this issue. Perhaps this is the wrong place to post this? If so, where would be a better place to post this?

[The users of Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users) and [the moderators of Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/users?tab=moderators) cannot answer your question because we do not have access to the things which you have sent to Stack Exchange through [the contact page](https://askubuntu.com/contact). Only Stack Exchange staff have access to it.

Ask Ubuntu Meta *might* be a wrong place to post this. Maybe you can post this in Meta Stack Exchange, but I am not 100% sure.

---

> It is now five weeks after I asked this question and there is NO response. Is there anyone who actually READS this forum? Is there a different place I should ask this question? Perhaps "Ask Ubuntu Meta Meta" exists?

I am sorry for the late response. Generally, the users of Ask Ubuntu or the moderators of Ask Ubuntu post an answer or add a comment in meta posts as soon as possible. Maybe they missed your post or did not know what to say to you.

There is no "*Ask Ubuntu Meta Meta*". You can try to talk to [Community Manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40354)s in chatrooms. [They](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338) are mostly there in [Meta Stack Exchange chatrooms](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/). But there's no guarantee that they will reply to you in the chatrooms.

Comment: I wrote this over six mounts ago! I honestly don't recall if I got the "Thank you for contacting the Stack Exchange Team". As for the rest: "You should receive a response shortly." Six month is not even remotely close to "shortly" (maybe it would be if I was a snail) P.S. I resolved the issues by dumping Ubuntu and getting a different Linux distro.

Comment: @RichardJUschold If you don't mind, may I know the reason for contacting Stack Exchange? If the community can help you with your issue, we will try :)

Comment: To both random people: This happened so long ago, it is no longer reverent to me, though it could be to others in the future. In late Dec and early Jan Several of my posts to Ask Ubuntu were closed for dubious and frankly invalid reasons. One: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1303495/ubuntu-20-04-is-the-worst-linux-ive-had-in-25-years?noredirect=1#comment2216441_1303495 Two: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304164/ubuntu-20-04-is-the-worst-linux-ive-had-in-25-years-take-2 You can look those up, if you have sufficient privileges. Continued ...

Comment: I contacted https://askubuntu.com/contact (about Jan 1 or 2) for possible reprimands to those who behaved badly to me, on Ask Ubuntu. No response to those, either. Finally, someone responded to my "anybody home?" requests.

Comment: @RichardJUschold Apologies for not attending your question here... as Random Person explained *contact us* goes to some higher echelons beyond Ask Ubuntu, so we don't know why you didn't get a response - that's probably why nobody felt like answering. However, those questions were quite rightly closed by our standards as they weren't answerable within the scope of the site. Bug reports should be made on [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) (the development platform for Ubuntu). As for unkind comments, sorry about that - it tends to happen when people express anger and frustration in posts.

Comment: My original post VERY clearly stated that I had submitted 3 bugs to Launchpad, with NO results. Which is why I submitted the fourth bug here, hoping for better results. It was far worse here, I was insulted! Someone on my first post suggested I should use Launchpad for the bugs, as have you, Mod: Zanna. It is EXTREMELY frustrating to realize that people read so poorly, that they suggest I try something that I CLEARLY stated I have already tried! And here you are, six months later, repeating the same old nonsense. Good buy, people!

Comment: @RichardJUschold Ask Ubuntu has NEVER been a true bug reporting location.  Filing bugs on Launchpad is the proper way to file bugs, however not all packages are actively monitored so you are **NOT** guaranteed responses to your bugs.  Ask Ubuntu has always closed bug reports as offtopic, this would've been no exception to that rule.